# Spring Controller Content-Type

Tags: spring

I've defined a controller (see below), and specified that it produces JSON, however when requesting (using curl), a `Content-Type` of `text/html` is returned. I can override this by setting the header on the `HttpServletResponse` directly, but I wasn't sure if this was expected behavior, and if so, if what I am doing is the correct workaround.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Test { 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {

        return "some/freemarker/template/path";

    } 

}
```

`Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`

**Update:**

I should add that I am using Freemarker as the view technology.

Comment: What is the actual content body you are getting? I doubt that it is not actually JSON but an HTML page, possibly a tomcat 404 or any other

Comment: From [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--): `request only mapped if the Accept matches one of these media types`. So, when requesting, did you add an `Accept` header to your request, valued to `application/json`?

Comment: @shazin The body is valid JSON being produced from Freemarker templates.

Comment: @sp00m  Yes, I tried `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json"`

Comment: show your complete controller. I mean controller methods

Answer (score 0):

In order for your Controller to return JSON you need to either do

Mark all your controller methods with `@ResponseBody`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Test { 
    @ResponseBody
    public String json() {

    }
}
```

Use `@RestController` annotation

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Test { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these work in my case.  In my case I use `@Controller` as I am returning a view name that resolves to a Freemarker template tht produces the JSON.  It appears it is the Freemarker template engine is setting the `Content-Type`, which Spring leaves as-is.  When I used `@RestController` then the string I am returning from the method body is not resolved to a template.  When I used `@ResponseBody` the template was unable to be resolved for some reason...